# URL query does not filter as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have made a small api together with a collection in mongodb which I named just 'test'. Every document in it has two fields - 'letter' and 'nmbr', the value of 'letter' being either 'x' or 'z' or 'y', and the value of 'nmbr' either a positive integer or a negative integer. Then I wrote this piece of code:

```js
app.get('/tests/:par?nmbr[gt]=0', (req, res) => {
    Test.find({letter: req.params.par, nmbr: {$gt: 0}})
        .then(data => res.status(200).json({data}));
});
```

When I sent this GET request in postman - `localhost:5000/tests/x?nmbr[gt]=0`, I expected to receive as a response only those documents, in which the value of 'letter' is 'x' and the value of 'nmbr' is a positive integer.
Instead, in the response were included not only those documents, in which the value of 'letter' is 'x', but also the documents in which the value of 'nmbr' is a negative number.
So my question is why? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Express query strings don't work like that.

In order to access the query strings from the `req.query` object you don't need to specify them in your route handler in the same way you would with query params.

In order to get your desired results you can implement this approach:

```bash
http://localhost:5000/tests/x?nmbr=0
```

```js
app.get('/tests/:par', (req, res) => {
    Test.find({
        letter: req.params.par, // req.params.par = 'x'
        nmbr: {$gt: req.query.nmbr} // req.query.nmbr = 0
    }).then(data => {
        res.status(200).json({data})
    });
});
```

If you wanted to parameterise the numerical comparison operators e.g. `$gt`, `$lt` etc then you could do something like this:

```bash
http://localhost:5000/tests/x?nmbr=0&op=gt
```

```js
app.get('/tests/:par', (req, res) => {
    let query;
    switch (req.query.op) { //< Check which operator you want to use $gt, $lt etc
        case 'gt':
            query = {$gt: req.query.nmbr};
            break;
        case 'lt':
            query = {$lt: req.query.nmbr};
            break;
        default:
            query = {$gt: req.query.nmbr};
    }
    Test.find({
        letter: req.params.par,
        nmbr: query
    }).then(data => {
        res.status(200).json({data})
    });
});
```